# Identify HTML nodes in XDocument for replacement and translation to Json

Tags: c#, html, json, xml, linq-to-xml

I have XML that contains HTML tags. Using `XDocument` I can find the node and replace the contents to remove the HTML tags. Is there a way to identify the node with the HTML tag so the same replacement can be done on ALL nodes? Here is some sample XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myFields>
  <Request_Description>
    <html>
            <div>test</div>
        </html>
  </Request_Description>
  <Alternatives>
    <html>
      <div>n/a</div>
    </html>
  </Alternatives>
  <Outcome>
    <html>
      <div>n/a</div>
    </html>
  </Outcome>
</myFields>
```

And here is how I figured out how to replace the HTML for a single node by name.

```
XElement req_desc = newxdoc.Root.Element("Request_Description");
if (req_desc != null)
{
    XElement replacenode = new XElement(req_desc.Name, req_desc.Value);
    req_desc.Parent.Add(replacenode);
    req_desc.Remove();
}
```

I could do the same thing for "Alternatives" and "Outcome". But each of those nodes should be identifiable by the fact that their next child has the local name of "html". How can I find those elements whose first child has the local name of "html" and then perform the replacement steps I do above to remove that HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Descendants`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.descendants?view=netframework-4.7.2) method of `XDocument` to find all XML elements in the document whose first child has a local name of `"html"` as follows:

```
var query = from e in newxdoc.Descendants()
            //find those elements whose first child has the local name of "html"
            let child = e.Elements().FirstOrDefault()               
            where child != null && child.Name.LocalName == "html"
            select e;

foreach (var element in query.ToList())
{
    // Remove html and replace with plain text.
    var replacenode = new XElement(element.Name, element.Value);
    element.ReplaceWith(replacenode);
}
```

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RQPNk1).